# How to get Updated Messages from Message Center using the Office 365 Service Communications API

Tags: office365

I'm looking for an *efficient* way to get **(Updated)** messages from the Message Center according to the screenshot.

Using the **Office 365 Service Communications API** is straight forward, but according to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office-365-management-api/office-365-service-communications-api-reference#get-messages) we can't filter nor order by `LastUpdatedTime`. As far as I can see, the only reliable way to detect updated messages is by comparing `StartTime < LastUpdatedTime`.

Trying to order by `LastUpdateTime` results in the expected error message and matches the documentation.

```
"message": "The query specified in the URI is not valid. Order by 'LastUpdatedTime' is not allowed. To allow it, set the 'AllowedOrderByProperties' property on EnableQueryAttribute or QueryValidationSettings.",
```

Without the ability to set an `$orderby` ODATA filter for `LastUpdateTime desc`, there is no efficient way to get updated messages. It would require to load *all* messages and do the filtering client-side.

There are hundreds of messages and the potential period between `StartTime` and `LastUpdateTime` is unknown, so I can't even filter to a subset (e.g. `StartTime gt 7 days`). One must always process every message to be sure not to miss an updated one.

I want to receive the exact same representation and order of the messages (updated and non-updated) as in the Message Center itself and according to the screenshot.

Am I missing a better option?

[image: Message Center Messages (Updated)]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since there is neither an answer from the community nor can I find any hint in the documentation, I've implemented my own *client-side* logic from observation.

#### Solution

```bsh
# Get all Messages from Message Center
function Get-ServiceCommMessages {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param (
        $DaysToSync
    )

    # Invoke-ServiceCommMethod is just a wrapper function for Invoke-WebRequest and Access Token acquisition.
    # https://github.com/sebastianzolg/PSServiceComm
    $messages = Invoke-ServiceCommMethod -Method '/ServiceComms/Messages' | Sort-Object LastUpdatedTime -Descending

    If($PSBoundParameters.ContainsKey('DaysToSync')){
        $messages = $messages | Where-Object LastUpdatedTime -ge (Get-Date).AddDays(-$daysToSync).Date
    }

    $messages | Add-Member -MemberType ScriptMethod -Name "IsUpdated" -Value {
        ($this.LastUpdatedTime -ge ($this.StartTime).AddHours(1)) -and ($this.Title -match [Regex]::Escape('(Updated)'))
    } -Force

    return $messages
}
```

```bsh
# Get all messages for the last 5 days and filter for updates
$messages = Get-ServiceCommMessages -DaysToSync 5
$messages | Where-Object { $_.IsUpdated() }
```

An **update** is considered as a message that satisfies the following conditions:

- `Title contains '(Updated)'`
- `LastUpdatedTime > StartTime + 1 Hour`

I've packed the logic into a very simple *PowerShell Core* Module, which you can find on [Github](https://github.com/sebastianzolg/PSServiceComm).